# Open word in Report Viewer

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, pdf-generation, openxml-sdk, sql-server-openxml

Im using a ASP.Net 4. I want to be able to display a word document in the microsoft report viewer . This document is uploaded by the user and needs to be displayed in the report viewer ?
How do i go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to display a word document in a report viewer !

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/28d2aaad-f65d-4743-bcab-ccf311bbd58c/load-report-viewer-with-a-word-document?prof=required

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a hyperlink in your reportviewer
2. Point the hyperlink to an aspx page where the aspx page loads a word document